# PhantomJS to Chromeheadless with navigator.userAgent

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, google-chrome-headless

I'm migrating PhantomJS to Chromeheadless in my project. The project is writen in Angular1.x and has *.spec.js files for test. I have done the following changes to use Chromeheadless.

karma.conf.js

```
// browsers: ['PhantomJS']
browsers: ['ChromeHeadless']
```

package.json

```
"karma": "^1.7.1",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0"
```

Tests failing where ever *.spec.js setting different userAgent.

```
window.navigator = {
  userAgent: 'Firefox;'
}

window.navigator = {
  userAgent: 'iPad;'
}
```

This is working fine for PhantomJS but throws `"cannot assign to readonly property navigator of object '#<Window>'"` for ChromeHeadless.

Here is how i get my Window object.

myfile.spec.js

```
'use strict';
describe('My test description', function(){
  var rootScope, compile, window, $document, browser, scope, timeout;
  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile, $window, _$document_, _browser_, $timeout;){
    rootScope = $rootScope;
    compile = $compile;
    window = $window;
    $document = _$document_;
    browser = _browser_;
    timeout = $timeout;
  }));
  ...
  ...
  ...
});
```

Searched in internet and could not find any solution or topic related to my issue. What changes should be done to make window object not read only so that i can assign other userAgents? Can anyone help on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This occours because in strict mode it's not possible to assign a read only property, and for some reason PhantomJS do no catch it. I already had some others problems with PhantomJS too, like array sort.

I don't know if you want it, but if you remove **'use strict'**, you could see that this error will not occour anymore.

UPDATE:
Try to set user agent like this:

```
Object.defineProperty(window.navigator, 'userAgent', {value: 'Firefox'});
```

or

```
Object.defineProperty(window.navigator, 'userAgent', {value: 'iPad'});
```